# Простой компилятор C#

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте!

Подскажите какой-нибудь компилятор для C#, чтобы установка была легкой и быстрой.

Спасибо!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Начиная с Windows Vista, .NET  Framework (разные версии) входит в дистрибутив операционной системы. Как справедливо заметил @aghasalim, для простой компиляции не нужно устанавливать дополнительных программ.

Для пробы можно набросать в блокноте текст программы (hello.cs), например:

```
using System;

namespace Sample {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
        }
    }
}
```

Затем скомпилировать:

```
> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\csc.exe /nologo hello.cs
```

И выполнить:

```
> hello.exe
Hello, World!
```

Если нужна полноценная среда, то Visual C# Express - лучший вариант для начала.

Answer (score 3):

Компилятор C# входит в стандартную установку самой .NET, поэтому программы на нём можно создавать и компилировать даже без инструментальных средств. По умолчанию устанавливается в

> `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\csc.exe`

Answer (score 0):

Если совсем легко и быстро - LinqPad

Answer (score 0):

Например, [SharpDevelop](http://www.sharpdevelop.net/OpenSource/SD/Download/). легко ставится, полноценная IDE, на мой взгляд, и не "весит" мало.

Answer (score -1):

Легкая и быстрая установка+легкая работа -> Visual Studio Express C#